# How to retrieve the background image url defined in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a div
`<div id="div_a" style="background-image:url('xxx')"></div>`

Then I can get the url info by using

```
document.getElementById("div_a").style.backgroundImage
```

to get its url info.

However if the style is defined in CSS the code above would return blank

Anything wrong with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "in CSS" - in a separate CSS class?

Comment: oh sry for the ambiguity, I mean the style sheet linked in <head>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the computed styles [getComputedStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle)

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div_a"), null).getPropertyValue('background-image')
```

Comment: Which browsers does this work in, though, exactly? Getting the computed style is a traditionally very tricky business.

Comment: @Pekka works fine in IE9/FF12/Chrome19 not yet tested in other versions though. Not sure if it works in prior IE versions